# Visual Studio Code does not pull Standard Objects

Tags: metadata, vs-code

I have run SFDX: Create Project with Manifest and then successfully ran SFDX: Authorize an Org to connect it with my sandbox.
Here is a part of my package.xml

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

Try as a might, right clicking on the package.xml and selecting SFDC: Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org does not fetch me the standard objects like Account, Opportunity etc though I see all Custom Objects are downloaded perfectly in my local system (all 50-60 of them).

I ran now SFDX: Refresh SObject Definitions but to no avail. I can not see Standard Objects in my local folder.

I could try to remove the wildcard from the package however then I have to type all the custom objects and standard object names. I would do it only if I am sure it is the last option as there are so many of them. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Add:
I checked similar issue faced by user which is yet unsolved:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000ILdcQAG

I have VS Code 1.37.1

Comment: I have VSC 1.37.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_package_by_component_type.htm) it is supposed to behave like that.

> The wildcard symbol does not apply to all metadata types. For example,
>   using the wildcard with the CustomObject type name will not retrieve
>   standard objects. To retrieve a standard object, you must explicitly
>   name the object in package.xml. Likewise, if you want to retrieve
>   custom fields defined on standard objects, you must name the object
>   and field.

So, you need to specify `by names` for getting standard objects.

```
<types>
    <members>Account</members>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```